# proof of summation of event probability

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Consider an experiment with sample space $\Omega$ and events $E_i \subseteq \Omega, \forall i\in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that if

$$\sum^n_{i=1}P(E_i)>1$$ then there must exist at least two events that have a non-zero probability occurring together.

How do I begin a proof like this?

Comment: Use a proof by contradiction and the law of inclusion-exclusion to derive a contradiction $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^n E_i) > 1$.

Comment: Prove the contrapositive! That is, assume that any two events have a zero probability of occurring together, that is, assume the events are disjoint. What does that tell you about the sum of their probabilities?

Comment: Mr 373923(does it matter whether I call you in binary or decimal?), note that if $E_i$ were disjoint events, then $\cup E_i$ would be a well defined event whose probability would equal $\sum E_i$. But this is given to be greater than $1$, whence the $E_i$ cannot be disjoint, or there is some intersection which has non-zero probability of occuring.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:*

[Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) implies that

$Pr(E_1\cup E_2\cup E_3\cup E_4\cup\dots)=Pr(E_1)+Pr(E_2)+\dots-Pr(E_1\cap E_2)-Pr(E_1\cap E_3)-\dots +Pr(E_1\cap E_2\cap E_3)+\dots \pm\dots$

We further know that the probability of any event is at most $1$.

> Try to prove the contrapositive statement:  If $Pr(E_i\cap E_j)=0$ for every $i\neq j$ then $\sum\limits_{i=1}^nPr(E_i)\leq 1$